# Problem to plot GDP data coming from Wolfram Alpha

Tags: plotting, finance, wolfram-alpha-queries

I'm working with economic data and realized that I could extract it directly from *WolframAlpha* using _Mathematica.
So I did it. I extracted the GDP data of the country I'm studying.

```
nominal = 
  WolframAlpha[
   "nominal gdp of brazil", {{"History:GDP:WorldDevelopmentData", 1}, 
    "TimeSeriesData"}, 
   PodStates -> {"History:GDP:WorldDevelopmentData__Linear scale"}];
```

So until now I'm ok. The trouble begins when I try to plot it using `DateListPlot[nominal]` because I just get an empty frame? I noticed that the GDP comes in US dollars and maybe some additional parameters are needed. I looked for it in the doc but couldn't find the solution. Thank's for the help.

Here goes a sample of what I got

> ```
> {{{1960, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[1.51656*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]},
>    {{1961, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[1.52369*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]},
>    {{1962, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[1.99263*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]},
>    {{1963, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[2.30215*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]},
>    {{1964, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[2.12119*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]},
>    {{1965, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[2.179*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]},
>    {{1966, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[2.70627*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]},
>    {{1967, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[3.05918*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]},
>    {{1968, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[3.38759*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]},
>    {{1969, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[3.74589*10^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]}.........
> ```

Comment: He goes a sample

Comment: Nice to see another Brazilian user here!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept useful answers. (You now have three questions and no accepted answers.)

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why `DateListPlot` does not work with `Quantity`. Perhaps it's a bug?

But the workaround is very easy: using pattern replacements we extract the numerical values.

```
DateListPlot[nominal /. Quantity[x_, _] :> x, 
   FrameLabel -> {"year", "$ per year"}]
```

[image: example]

---

Browsing through the help, another option is `QuantityMagnitude`.

```
DateListPlot@QuantityMagnitude@nominal
```

---

`Part` is also very versatile. This should get rid of units:

```
ListPlot@nominal[[All, {1, 2}, 1]]
```

Note that this only works because we take just the first part of the date (the year).

Comment: Thank you @Ajasja! Great! But I wonder that the real issue is : Weren't MM supposed to deal with the units automatically when plotting? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @DiegoOliveira No idea, I don't the new units that often.